# Import a csv file into R containing multiple columns in one column?

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a csv file. The file contains the data separated by spaces in single column. The problem doesn't end here as there are certain places where extra column is present in some row. I want to split the data based(create column) based on the spaces. The data set is very huge so I don;t want to that manually. Please look at the sample data and let me know how can i import the file in desired format.

Please find below the sample data:

First row:

```
"3000 2010-09-10 01:06:10.144132-05 2010-09-10 01:06:10.018-05 353 Location No_en 5860    
 ""locx""=>""963"""  "locy"=>"3998"  "flew_id"=>"Campus>center>Layout Floor"
```

Most of the rows are like this but there are places where we have rows as mentioned below:

Second Row:

```
"3000 2010-09-10 01:06:10.129147-05 2010-09-10 01:06:10.015-05  353 Location Unit09 0085    ""locx""=>""873""" "locy"=>"30344" "con"=>"67676" "flew_Id"=>"Campus>Center>Layout Floor"
```

Here we have one extra column as con. which is not there in the other rows. Any thoughts??

Comment: If you provide a minimal example. I can write a small demo code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `read.csv(filename)` and the `strsplit(yourstring, pattern)` function for everyline.

Alternative approach:

```
read.csv(file,sep=space)
```

**[Updated]**

Comment: I don't think this will work without adding the `fill=TRUE` argument to account for those rows with different number of entries.

Comment: `fill = TRUE` is the default value, so it should work. Of course more information would help us.

Comment: It's the default for `read.csv` but not `read.table` , so be careful